# Percentages and inequalities

Tags: inequality

We have carried out a research among the school students on a snowy and chilly day, as to wether they are adequately dressed for the cold. Below are the results:

No kid was wearing all three of scarve, gloves and hat.
19 in 100 kids did not wear exactly one of the three accessories.
At least 67 in every 100 kids did not wear scarf.
At least 83 in every 100 kids did not wear gloves.
At least 73 in every 100 kids did not wear hat.

What is the minimum number of kids (in every 100) that did not wear any of the three accessories?

I tried to first get the boundaries:
First condition says that 81% of the kids were wearing exactly 2 accessories, since 3 is not possible.
Similarly, at most 33% of the kids were wearing scarf, at most 17% gloves and at most 27% hat. If they were all wearing different accessories each, then at most 33+17+27=77 would be wearing something, so minimum 23 would not be wearing anything and this is the lower boundary. But we know that 81 kids were wearing exactly 2 accessories. So at maximum 17 are wearing both scarf and gloves, at maximum 27 scarf and hat and at maximum 17 gloves and hat. 
Can you help me to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Let  $A $ be the event of wearing a scarf, $B $ wearing gloves, and $C $ wearing hats. We have: $$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C|-|A \cap B|-|B \cap C|-|A \cap C|+|A \cap B \cap C|$$

We have: $|A \cap B \cap C|=0, |\text{ Universe }| =100, |A \cap B| + |B \cap C|+|A \cap C|=19, |A|<33, |B|<17, |C|<27$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Dear Rohan, thanks a lot for your reply. I find minimum value to be 42 - is this so?

Comment: The answer is supposed to be 32. $100-(33+17+27-19)=32$

Comment: Dear Rohan, I was told that the answer is not correct (no further explanations provided) - I can't figure out where a mistake might be. Any thoughts? Maybe a graphic solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: Ooops it is 42 not 32 :)